# Screen Saver unable to use keyboard arrows

Tags: macbook-pro

Previously, when my screen saver was going with photos, I was able to go forward or backward through the photos if I wished by using the keyboard left and right arrow keys. Now, they just close the screen saver. A new bug or "feature" in the latest Mojave update?